# How do I model a longitudinal tensile strain in a laminate composite using Abaqus software?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, simulation, abaqus

I want to be able to measure the strain response in a material composed of 2 lamina, bottom one (0) top one half (0) half (90), and see the differences in the unidirectional versus the bidirectional area.

I've been trying with the Lamina function, and using a negative pressure at one edge where I want the load, and bounding the other edge with boundary conditions. The error it gives me is `(Lamina can only be used with plane stress elements)`.

How can I get past this error? Do I need to use a different function?

Comment: I'm closing this question as "unclear" as it has attracted a number of low-quality answers, and has not seen meaningful updates in over two years.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing more about your problem the first thing that you need to do is make sure that you are using the right geometry and elements.

To use that representation you need to use:

- 2D geometry
- Mesh it as shells
- Assign a plain stress assumption

Comment: +1. As one of this site's top users in the Abaqus tag, I wonder if you've seen this question and/or if you might know the answer to it? https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/2055/5